# C# Split array of coordinates by higher distance between Z numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, distance

I am making coil spring laser scanner for measuring and laser gives me values only if it hits that spring. So I have array of X,Z points like: `"10,5; 11,6; 12,7; 11,8; 10,9; 10,15; 11,16; 12,17; 11,18; 10,19"` etc. I hope you understand it - here is picture of it 
[image: explaining how laser measures spring]

How can I split that array by "big space in Z coord" -- how can I separate those spring "tops"? (I don't know how to call it:D) I will be ok with just those highest X diameter points (like 12,7; 12,17).

EDIT: I'll try to explain more.
I have array of X,Z points (X is length, Z is height). It looks like this: {[10,5], [11,6], [12,7], [11,8], [10,9], [10,15], [11,16], [12,17], [11,18], [10,19]}. Comma is separating X and Z coordinate (like on image). I need to detect the gap between those groups of points - between [10,9] and [10,15], so I can calculate how many threads that spring has - and get only those highest X points - [12,7] and [12,17]. 
My idea was iterate through that array and check if previous Z is lower than xx, but I couldn't manage what to do next.
I'm still learning C# and most of the time I spend Googling and trying, but for this I even hadn't any idea what and how to try :/

Comment: so what have you tried? you want to split it on the space have you tried that, what was wrong with the output

Comment: You should also define what you mean by "big space"?

Comment: Where is the problem?  "10,5; 11,6; 12,7; 11,8; 10,9; 10,15; 11,16; 12,17; 11,18; 10,19".Split(' '); should work?

Comment: @Thierry OP doesn't have a string, they have an array of points, and they want to group those points where there is a large gap in the Z value.

Comment: The title of this question is very easy to misunderstand. "Space between numbers" should really be "distance" or "gap between numbers"...

Comment: There is a big gap between z=[19,15] and z=[9,5], so he probably wants to detect this gap...

Comment: @waka Indeed, though I do think they may be starting with a string too

Comment: Well, I had an idea that I will go through whole array and check if previous Z is higher than xx, but I couldn't manage what to do next, how to get highest X from it and continue finding another. I know there will be simple solution, but I cannot find it out :/

Comment: And yeah, sorry, I couldn't find the right word - "gap" or "distance" is right

Comment: @TheSpixxyQ You need to: 1-Show us the source data and expected output in code. Do you have a string as a starting point or do you already have an array? 2-Show us what you have tried already, this is not a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: The splitting and parsing here is irrelevant to the problem and should be done first. Simply create a struct Point(x, z) and parse your string into an array of points. Then iterate over that array and do your gap detection. If you can't figure that out, [edit] your question to be about _that_.

Comment: Your question is first quite unclear and second far too broad without *any* own attemps. 1. What is a gap? How "big" is "big"? 2. Where *specifically* are you stuck? What did you try? We´re definitly not giving you the complete code for such a complex issue.

Comment: Your edit makes it a bit clearer, however you still didn´t provide any code that shows your *specific* issue.

Comment: As in *any* other program: before **coding**, *think* what you want to do. Create some diagram showing your steps you need to do to achieve your goal. *Afterwards* think about how to code that. Without a clear idea no-one can give you *any* (meaningful) code here. Don´t make the second step ("**How** to code that") before the first ("**What** to code").

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I appreciate it :) And thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `XZ` class like

```
public class XZ
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public XZ(int x, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Z = z;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"X = {X}, Z = {Z}";
    }
}
```

we can define a:

```
static IEnumerable<XZ[]> SplitByZGap(IEnumerable<XZ> points, int gap)
{
    var group = new List<XZ>();

    bool first = true;
    int lastZ = 0;

    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else if (Math.Abs(point.Z - lastZ) >= gap)
        {
            var group2 = group.ToArray();
            group.Clear();
            yield return group2;
        }

        lastZ = point.Z;
        group.Add(point);
    }

    {
        var group2 = group.ToArray();
        group.Clear();
        yield return group2;
    }
}
```

That will split a collection of `XZ` points by "gap" (so distance in the Z axis)

We can define some data like:

```
var points = new[]
{
    new XZ(10,5),
    new XZ(11,6),
    new XZ(12,7),
    new XZ(11,8),
    new XZ(10,9),
    new XZ(10,15),
    new XZ(11,16),
    new XZ(12,17),
    new XZ(11,18),
    new XZ(10,26),
};
```

(note that I've changed the last z coordinate from 19 to 26)

And then:

```
var res = SplitByZGap(points, 6).ToArray();
```

Comment: "We´re definitly not giving you the complete code for such a complex issue" Hmmm, obviously we do anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It took probably him more to create the graph than to me to write the code :-) Equivalent exchange :-)

Comment: Unfortunately though, you're giving him fish instead of a fishing rod :(

Comment: @DavidG Yes you are right... But at least he put some work in writing the question. And he had an half idea about what to do (written in a comment). Probably he didn't know about `yield` and using a `List<>` for groping data (or using directly a `List<int[]>`). Sometimes showing *is* teaching.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Yeah, I didn't know about `yield` and also I have never used `IEnumerable` before. Btw. I am that person who can learn alot from just reading complete code, so this gave me more than just piece of code. I understood it how it works and what it does and next time I will know how to use it :)

Answer (score -3):

Simple using String Split.  To get gap look at slope of points to separate cycles.  Code below is one way of accomplishing the split.  You cannot reorder points like you example which may not give proper results.  It looks like you picture and list of points are reverse from each other.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    enum State
    {
        UNKNOWN,
        POSITIVE,
        NEGATIVE
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "10,5; 11,6; 12,7; 11,8; 10,9; 10,15; 11,16; 12,17; 11,18; 10,19";
            string[] splitSemicolon = input.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Point[] points = splitSemicolon.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',' })).Select(x => new Point(int.Parse(x.FirstOrDefault()), int.Parse(x.LastOrDefault()))).ToArray();            

            State state = State.UNKNOWN;
            List<Cycle> cycles = new List<Cycle>();
            Cycle newCycle = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                double slope = 0;
                if (points[i].X == points[i - 1].X)
                {
                    slope = points[i].Y - points[i - 1].Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    slope = (points[i].Y - points[i - 1].Y) / (points[i].X - points[i - 1].X);
                }
                switch (state)
                {
                    case State.UNKNOWN:
                        newCycle = new Cycle();
                        cycles.Add(newCycle);
                        if (slope < 0)
                        {
                            newCycle.negativeSlope = new List<Point> { points[0], points[1] };
                            state = State.NEGATIVE;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newCycle.positiveSlope = new List<Point> { points[0], points[1] };
                            state = State.POSITIVE;
                        }
                        break;

                    case State.POSITIVE :
                        if (slope > 0)
                        {
                            newCycle.positiveSlope.Add(points[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newCycle = new Cycle();
                            cycles.Add(newCycle);
                            newCycle.negativeSlope = new List<Point>() { points[i] };
                            state = State.NEGATIVE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case State.NEGATIVE:
                        if (slope > 0)
                        {
                            newCycle.positiveSlope = new List<Point>() { points[i] };
                            state = State.POSITIVE;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newCycle.negativeSlope.Add(points[i]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Cycle
    {
        public List<Point> negativeSlope { get; set; }
        public List<Point> positiveSlope { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will split ony *every* element, not just on the "big gaps" - whatever that means.

Comment: This is the first step.  The next step is to find where the slope is changing.  Each cycle contains points where the slope is going negative and points where the slope is going positive.

Comment: So if this is only half an answer, why post it at all?

Comment: Do not know OPs level of experience.  Also do not know if this is homework.  I updated anwser anyway.